# Where information for npm link is saved in local project

Tags: node.js, npm

Imagine I have executed following command:

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis              # link-install the package
```

Where does npm save this information in local project `~/projects/node-bloggy` that its dependency `redis` is linkd to other directory?